# Segmentation Fault when Cross Compiling for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, sqlite, segmentation-fault, raspberry-pi

I have written a simple piece of C code that uses sqlite3 to create a new database and add things to it that the user inputs. It compiles and runs fine when I compile it for x86 on my PC (changing the directory of the used db file), the problem occurs when I cross compile for use on a Raspberry Pi 2. It builds/compiles fine however when I try to run the executable on the Pi all I get in response is "Segmentation fault" and nothing more.

Here is my code however I'm not convinced it's the code that's the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>



int main()
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   int rc;
   char *sql;
   char *sql1;
   char sql2[128];
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int DataToAdd = 1;
   int TempID[64], TempReg[64], TempData[64];
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   char message[128];

   rc = sqlite3_open("/home/testing/Basic.db", &db);

   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return -1;
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }




       printf("Do you have data to add? (1=Y, 0=N)\n");
       scanf("%d", &DataToAdd);

       while(DataToAdd){

           if (DataToAdd) {
               printf("Enter Modbus Device ID\n");
               scanf("%d", &TempID[i]);
               printf("Enter Register Number\n");
               scanf("%d", &TempReg[i]);
               printf("Enter Data Value\n");
               scanf("%d", &TempData[i]);

           }else {
               printf("No more data to add...");
               break;
           }
           i++;
           printf("Do you have more data to add? (1=Y, 0=N)\n");
           scanf("%d", &DataToAdd);
       }

   sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MODBUS";
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   if( rc ){

       fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);

       sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);

      }else{

       fprintf(stdout, "Table dropped successfully or was not present\n");

      }

   sql1 = "CREATE TABLE MODBUS(ID INT NOT NULL, REG INT NOT NULL, DATA INT NOT NULL);";
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql1, NULL, NULL, NULL);

     if( rc ){

       fprintf(stdout, "Table not created\n");
       fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);

       sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);

     }else{

       fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");

     }

   for (j=0; j<i; j++)
   {
       sprintf(sql2, "INSERT INTO MODBUS(ID, REG, DATA) VALUES(%d, %d, %d);", TempID[j], TempReg[j], TempData[j]);
       rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql2, NULL, NULL, NULL);

         if( rc ){
           sprintf(message, "Item %d could not be added\n", (j+1));
           fprintf(stdout, message);
           fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
           break;

           sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);

         }else{
           sprintf(message, "Item %d added successfully\n", (j+1));
           fprintf(stdout, message);

         }

   }

   sqlite3_close(db);

   return 0;
}
```

I then copy the build output executable to the raspberry Pi manually and change directories to its' location via SSH and try to run it. This is where the error occurs. I had a previous error with this where it was due to a lack of permissions on the executable and I have done to this file what fixed it for me previously to no avail, I have also changed permissions on the database file. Any ideas as what could be causing the fault this time?

EDIT::

Oh should've said, I attempted to cross-debug however the "Segmentation Fault" error results in it terminating before I see anything happen.

Comment: Given the lack of bounds checking, there is probably some undefined behavior in there.

Comment: Surely this would also stop me being able to run it when I compile it for use on my Desktop PC too though?

Comment: There is no requirement for undefined behavior to be consistent. It's *undefined*.

Comment: Debug it! You have all of the means to do it.

Comment: Oh should've said, I attempted to cross-debug however the "Segmentation Fault" error results in it terminating before I see anything happen.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. It has to execute at least one instruction before failing.

Comment: When I begin to debug in eclipse it starts, then as soon as I "step into" for the first time the process terminates

Comment: Eclipse? attach GDB to it if possible.

Comment: Use `si` in the `gdb` command line instead. "Step into" is not working well sometimes (you can do it from eclipse console).

Comment: Is the sqlite lib correctly installed into target system?

Comment: @LPs I believe so, however I would be interested in checking, any idea as to how I can do that?

Comment: `cd /usr/lib` and `find . -name "*sqlite*.*"` and check the listed results

Comment: ./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.so.0                                                         
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.so                                                           
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.a
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.la
./python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so




                                                                                                                            that is the output from that search "arm-linux-gnueabihf" is my cross compiler

Comment: What does `ulimit -s` show on the Pi? You're putting a fair amount on the stack. I've never programmed on a Pi but presumably the stack isn't huge.

Comment: @DaV - It shows 8192

Comment: @Shark Its in the eclipse debug environment however it is linked to gdb-multiarch to be able to crossdebug for the Pi

Comment: I know what it is, and from experience - attaching GDB manually and doing things on your own yields **far, far** better/clearer results. Stick to Eclipse debugger for java :/

Comment: is that just by using "gdb ....."?

Comment: Also, another thing worth mentioning is - Raspberry Pi's integer isn't 4 bytes but only 2. The segfault could like in a place where you assumed it's variable types have the same bit width as on a normal system.
EDIT: No, you're free to try any other debugger, the GDB is the first I thought of. Second one is LLDB, but since you're using GCC - GDB makes the most sense.

Comment: Sorry, bit inexperienced with gdb, just ran it and got the following output: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000579da in ?? () where do I go from there? Is there an error log etc.?

Comment: @Shark there are clear benefits of using Eclipse as a front-end for `gdb`. Just know it's limitations.

Comment: @Shark The Raspberry Pi is an ARM machine. There are no 16-bit ARMs. The assertion that `int` is only 2 bytes on a Raspberry Pi is incorrect.

Comment: You got compiler warnings. 

     `gcc main.c -lsqlite3
    main.c: In function ‘main’:
    main.c:91:29: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
                 fprintf(stdout, message);
                                 ^
    main.c:99:29: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
                 fprintf(stdout, message);`

Comment: @EOF you're right, I confused it with Arduino. My mistake.