# Segmentation Fault when Cross Compiling for Raspberry Pi the simplest program

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, remote-debugging

I'm experimenting with the most simplest program I can came up with, to check out cross-compiling and remote debugging on a raspberry pi 1b.

I know that this might be seen as "duplicate" of [Segmentation Fault when Cross Compiling for Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616768/segmentation-fault-when-cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi)
Unfortunately there is no answer to that 5 year old question.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    return 0;   
} /* END main() */
```

These are the compiler options I use

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pedantic -Wall -W -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Werror -ggdb -std=gnu99 -fpic -marm -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -c -o test.o
```

These are the linker options I use

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -ggdb -Wl,--print-memory-usage -Wl,-Map="bin/test.map" -Wl,--cref test.o -o bin/test
```

I transfer the binary with scp to the raspberry pi. When I try to execute it on the pi I immediatly get an "Segmentation fault" - Why? I don't see the problem, but guess it has something to do either my cross-toolchain or with an option I miss.

Also I installed gdbserver on the pi. I can connect to it using gdb-multiarch on the local machine. As soon as I "run" I get the same result:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Breakpoint 1 at 0xc08: file 
/home/dev/src/main.c, line 3.
Reading /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 from remote target...
Warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access 
files locally instead.
Reading /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 from remote target...
Reading /lib/69cc7c8461969efd3718272bbf9f5284465419.debug from remote target...
Reading /lib/.debug/69cc7c8461969efd3718272bbf9f5284465419.debug from remote 
target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug//lib/69cc7c8461969efd3718272bbf9f5284465419.debug from remote 
target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/lib//69cc7c8461969efd3718272bbf9f5284465419.debug from remote 
target...
Reading target:/usr/lib/debug/lib//69cc7c8461969efd3718272bbf9f5284465419.debug from 
remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so from remote target...
Reading /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4720c484c733362ad0713e1328e88f42334bed.debug 
from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf/.debug/4720c484c733362ad0713e1328e88f42334bed.debug from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf/4720c484c733362ad0713e1328e88f42334bed.debug from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf//4720c484c733362ad0713e1328e88f42334bed.debug from remote target...
Reading target:/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf//4720c484c733362ad0713e1328e88f42334bed.debug from remote target...
Reading /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/193a3bab8dcbe8499da5b220f646fc717d6032.debug from 
remote target...
Reading /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/.debug/193a3bab8dcbe8499da5b220f646fc717d6032.debug 
from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug//lib/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf/193a3bab8dcbe8499da5b220f646fc717d6032.debug from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/lib/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf//193a3bab8dcbe8499da5b220f646fc717d6032.debug from remote target...
Reading target:/usr/lib/debug/lib/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf//193a3bab8dcbe8499da5b220f646fc717d6032.debug from remote target...
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0044fcb6 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

This is the version of the compiler I use:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 9.4.0
```

I have no glue what is going on here.

---- Edit ----

@Frant the options doesn't change anything. However I downloaded a docker container to compile for the pi. I noticed a difference in using file on each of the binaries.

Output for the binary utilizing the apt-package (does SIGSEG):

```
$ file bin/hello
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
```

Output for the binary utilizing the docker container (does run):

```
$ file bin/hello
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26,
```

My guess is that glibc is to new for the one used on the pi - correct?

Comment: I'm not expert in this field, but this is the compiler that is provided by raspberri-pi for cross compiling, isn't it? I mean from raspberry-pi toolchain.

Comment: Very likely the shared libraries being used by your cross-compiler don't match the ones being used on the Pi at runtime.  Unfortunately this can be a major pain to fix.  Does it work if you compile and link using `-static`?

Comment: @Afshin
yes it it the offical toolchain - at least I think so, because I followed the instructions on https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

Adding -static to the compile options didn't change anything... 
Adding -static to the linker options caused the program to immediatly segfault when gdb tried to run it.

Comment: You may be missing some CPU specific compilation options: `-march=armv6zk -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s` The CPU architecture on the 1B is ARMV11, not Armv7-a, which may be the default for your toolchain,.